# Ruby on Rails - back button that will take you back to the previous page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to add a back button to any of my pages that will take you back to the previous page that you were on regardless of what that page is?

So if I have a person on my directors page that landed there from our contracts page it will take them back to contracts, and if a user landed there from our team page it will take them back to team..

Thanks so much

**edit for clarification...
If my user lands on the contract page and they submit a form and edit some stuff on the page I'd like them to be able to go back to the previous page but not go back to the form submission or the edit page

Answer (score 4):

Usually you can use [`link_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) with the symbol `:back` instead of a URL like this

```
<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

to return to the previous page.

But this, unfortunately, doesn't work in cases in which you want to skip certain pages (like a page with a form), because `:back` would simply return you to the previous URL from your history.

If you only want to return to certain pages but not to others, then you have to build that functionality on your own. I would start with pushing those pages into the session that you think are worth being on that list. For example, like this:

```
# in the `application_controller.rb`
private

def remember_page
  session[:previous_pages] ||= []
  session[:previous_pages] << url_for(params.to_unsafe_h) if request.get?
  session[:previous_pages] = session[:previous_pages].uniq.first(2)
end

# in each controller that is worthy
before_action :remember_page, only: [:index, :show]
```

Now you will find the previous and the current page in the session if there was already a previous page. And you can return to that previous page with a helper like this:

```
# in a helper
def link_to_previous_page(link_title)
  link_to_if(
    session[:previous_pages].present? && session[:previous_pages].size > 1,
    link_title, 
    session[:previous_pages].first
  )
end
```

Which can be used in a view like this

```
<%= link_to_previous_page("return to previous page") %>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had someone else recomment this gem: https://github.com/Greyoxide/backpedal but I think I'm going to try using this instead.

Comment: What do you mean by controller page that is worthy? A any page that I would like my user to go back to? So no forms obviously... Is "before_action :remember_page, only: [:index, :show]" how rails keeps track of the previous URL?

Comment: Rails doesn't know how the previous page looked like. If there was a form on it or not. Therefore you need to tell Rails what pages to remember and which not. You can do that by calling `remember_page` before all actions that you want to remember. Or you can remember all pages and only skip the `before_action` for those that you do not want to remember. But Rails cannot make the decision for you.

Comment: Can you help explain ```session[:previous_pages] << url_for(params) if request.get?``` to me? I keep getting a ```unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash``` error and I'm trying to trouble shoot the issue myself. i just can't find url_for in rails very frequently so it has been difficult

Comment: [`url_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for) allows creating an URL from a hash. The params in the controller represent the current request. That means when the request was a get request (we do not want to return to post, put or delete requests) then add the current URL to the list of URLs to remember. Regarding the error: I updated my answer to address that issue.

Comment: Ideally this would be something to put into a [Kredis](https://github.com/rails/kredis) instance correct? At least that seems like a good feature to use Kredis instead of sessions.

Comment: Depends on your needs and your setup. Your apps session might already be stored in Redis or Memcached depending on your setup. Other apps might not use Redis at all and adding it just for this kind of feature might not be the most economic decision.

Comment: Shouldn't "unique" be "uniq"?

Comment: @DavidLewis You are right. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the solution provided by @spickermann, and it solved most of my problems. At first, I thought that I would want to be able to navigate beyond just the previous page, but after testing multiple iterations I found that the complexity increases too much, so I just stuck with the depth provided in his solution.

However, I did run into a couple of issues and would like to provide my take on his solution. The problems that I encountered were that sometimes the session[:previous_pages] would be empty, and that caused problems with the link_to_if method in the helper. This showed up on first launch of the app and when running my tests.

The second issue involved the deleting of a database record from within the show method. @Stephanie's example uses contracts. If I delete a contract from a list of contracts, then I had no problem as the record ID was not in the session[:previous_pages]. But if I deleted the contract from the show method, then session[:previous_pages] would contain a breadcrumb to the now deleted record, and the user would be served up a 404 response.

My solution is to delete it from the session[:previous_pages].

```
# in the file "application_controller.rb"
private

def remember_page
  session[:previous_pages] ||= []
  new_page = url_for(params.to_unsafe_h)
  return unless session[:previous_pages].last != new_page

  session[:previous_pages] << new_page if request.get?
  session[:previous_pages] = session[:previous_pages].last(2)
end
```

And:

```
#in the file "application_helper.rb"

def link_to_previous_page(link_title)
  return unless session[:previous_pages].present?

  link_to(link_title, session[:previous_pages].first)
end
```

Finally:

```
# in the contracts_controller.rb
def destroy
  @contract = Contract.find(params[:id]).destroy

if session[:previous_pages].present? && request.original_url == session[:previous_pages][1]
  session[:previous_pages] = session[:previous_pages].first(1)
end
flash[:notice] = 'Contract was successfully deleted.'

redirect_to action: 'index'
end
```

The before_action and link_to_previous_page remains unchanged.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the javascript method to go back to the previous page. This way the previous page will be loaded as it is without refreshing the content.

```
<%= link_to 'Back', 'javascript:history.back()' %>
```

Comment: this does not work after submit ex. We have some Malfunction record and on its show page we can add comments, when comment form is submitted page is reloaded and after that when you press back it returns you to the same show  page because that page was the previous page